# Naming files without extensions in PHP, how to add an extension to a file?

Tags: php, xml, file, rename

I am working in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), and I have some files without extensions.

Example:

```
MYfolder
    firstfile
    secondfile
    otherfile
```

And so on.

I want to list the files, and  give it all ".xml" extension. How do I do it in PHP?

Comment: Show the code you have tried...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<?php
    if ($handle = opendir('/MYfolder')) {
        while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
            rename($fileName, $filename.'xml');
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
?>
```

Comment: `false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))` That's interesting. I've been using `strpos($fileName, '.')!==0` and I'm guessing it does the same thing.

Comment: I see :) . I wish you get the output.

Comment: i tried this before also.i tried again.. i know the code is correct but its not doing it..anyway thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 1):

On Linux/Unix box:

```
exec('for F in your/directory/*; do mv $F{,.xml}; done');
```